# Type Mismatch trying to copy Text from 1 Word Doc to Another?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop, office-interop

Below is my current code. Execution works fine until I reach line `oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Range().FormattedText = rng.FormattedText;` where I catch an exception of `Type Mismatch`? What I'm trying to do at that point is copy the first section (page) of my Mail Merge Document, being the first record of the Mail Merge, and put it into a new Word Document instance to save as it's own document.

So if I have selected 4 records for the Mail Merge Document, this will give me a single word document titled "Letters Form1" with 4 pages, a letter to each record recipient. What I need to do, somehow, is save each of these 4 pages into their own Word Document for archiving and ease of indexing.

Can anyone with more experience in Word Interop assist me with this?

```
public void OpenAndReview()
        {
            try
            {
                string docSave = "C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Test.doc";

                //MergeDocLibrary mdl = new MergeDocLibrary();
                //mdl.mergeDocument(docSource, docLoc);

                // Original Mail Merge Document
                Word.Range rng;
                Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
                Word.Document oWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

                // New Document Instance
                Word.Application oNewWord = new Word.Application();
                Word.Document oNewWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

                // Set 'False' in PROD, 'True' in DEV
                oWord.Visible = true;
                oNewWord.Visible = true;
                Object oTemplatePath = docLoc;

                // Open Mail Merge Doc
                oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);

                // Open New Document
                oNewWrdDoc = oNewWord.Documents.Open(docSave);
                Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                // Open Mail Merge Datasource
                oWrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(docSource, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
                   oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

                MessageBox.Show(oWord.ActiveDocument.Name.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count.ToString());

                // Execute Mail Merge
                oWrdDoc.MailMerge.Execute();

                // Set Mail Merge Document as Active Doc
                //oWrdDoc.Activate();

                MessageBox.Show(oWord.ActiveDocument.Name.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count.ToString());

                // Select Section 1 of Mail Merge Doc?
                rng = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Range;


                // ERROR! - Type Mismatch
                // Place selected text into the new Document???
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Range().FormattedText = rng.FormattedText;


                // Save new docuemnt...?
                oNewWrdDoc.SaveAs2("SuccesfullySavedTest.doc");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {
                //


 }
        }
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you can have strings that ignore escaping by prefixing it with an @ symbol, eg `@"C:\Users\etc"` instead of `"C:\\Users\\etc"`

Comment: Hey, thanks! Did not know about that. Any ideas on my `Type Mistmatch` issue?

Answer (score 1):

FormattedText can only be set in the same Word Application. It will fail if the two documents are in different Word Application. Instead of oNewWord use oWord only.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem as you.
What worked for me was to use this code.

```
range = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Range;
range.Copy();

//Special pasting onto new word document
newDocument.Content.PasteSpecial(DataType: Word.WdPasteOptions.wdKeepSourceFormatting);
```